# Using .index() with a list that has repeated elements

Tags: python

So I'm checking a list and printing all the values that are equal to three

```
for item in top:
    if item == 3:
        print('recommendation found at:')
        print(top.index(item))
```

the problem is this will just continually print the first element that has the value 3. How can you print every the position of every element with the value 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
>>> top = [1, 3, 7, 8, 3, -3, 3, 0]
>>> hits = (i for i,value in enumerate(top) if value == 3)
```

This is a generator that will yield all indices `i` where `top[i] == 3`.

```
>>> for i in hits:
...     print(i)
... 
1
4
6
```

Answer (score 0):

From 
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html
Index: "Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x."

a simple solution would be:

```
for i in range(len(top)):
    if top[i] == 3:
        print('recommendation found at: ' + str(i))
```